# Uninitialised byte(s) Valgrind complaint - inexplicable

Tags: c++, memory, valgrind

Valgrind has kept complaining about uninitialized bytes and by trimming down in look for a minimal example I have ended up with this:

```
#include <valgrind/memcheck.h>

struct dummyObject{
    int foo;
    bool bar;

    dummyObject():foo(1),bar(true) {}
};

int main(){

    dummyObject dummy;

    VALGRIND_CHECK_VALUE_IS_DEFINED(dummy); 

    return 0;
}
```

Having two ints or two bools, or a single int or bool, cause no complaints. It looks as if having a class with members of different types leads to Valgrind complaining. This is not simply due to my explicit request for checking either; in a larger program where object similar to dummyObject gets used, I 'm getting the "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)" error.

My compiler is g++ 4.7.3 on a 64-bit linux, compiling with debug flags and no optimizations - or with, it makes no difference.

Is there something I 'm missing, or is it a false positive?

Comment: It complains on padding bytes which cannot be initialized by compiler.

Comment: Same problem here with gcc 4.7.2 and Valgrind 3.9.0. I'm quite new of C++ but this seem to me an huge issue in Valgrind. Here is somebody having the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19364942

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you check the size of your type you will probably find that the size doesn't match the sum of the size of the members. For example, on my system I get:

```
sizeof(dummy)=8 sizeof(int)=4 sizeof(bool)=1
```

when printing the different sizes. The difference is *padding* used to make sure the objects are aligned to addresses where they can be easily accessed by the system. It is probably this padding which is uninitialized.

Comment: Thank you! Using #pragma to pack the struct with zero padding indeed makes the complaint go away (though I will be suppressing the valgrind error instead).