# About data alignment of a specific struct

Tags: c++, performance, build, alignment

This is probably quite basic questions, but I came across them when trying to solve a certain Valgrind [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19364942/points-to-uninitialised-bytes-valgrind-errors/19365033?noredirect=1#comment28699424_19365033). Apparently the error were being caused by the uninitialized padding bytes on a custom struct. While I've already grasped the whole concept of structure padding, I still have doubts about how data alignment is managed. I've found a lot of info about the theme on several sites and Q&A right here, but I still have some lingering doubts:

Is the byte alignment (the size of the data chunk read) set system-wide, chosen by the compiler for the whole program, or specific for each structure in my code (and if so, is it hardcoded on the binary)? And what exactly is exactly is the relation to the system architecture (32 vs 64 bit)? How could I find the value that I am currently using as default?

Answer (score 1):

on 32 bit system it's 4 bytes, on 64 bit - 8 bytes
you can change alignment for specific structs/classes or get the default using pragma pack
[MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1.aspx)
[GCC also supports it](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure_002dPacking-Pragmas.html)
also you can find out the default value by declaring one char struct and using sizeof(). it will return the aligned size.